# How to "legalize" Ethers in the real world? Successfully pass any regulations, blocks and taxes

Tags: ether

For example I have collected 160000 ether using crowdfunding Ethereum contract.
And now I want to buy commercial real estate to take a rent and pay back to my token holders.

- So questions, how to actually do that?
- In which country to create real company and open bank account?
- In which jurisdictions company will fall into?
- How to proof legal origin of capital to legal instances?
- How to pay taxes only from revenue?
- Some other things to consider?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Also, be aware that there is a lot of room for speculation and opinion based answers, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The truth is that this is unexplored territory in many jurisdictions.
Services like [Otonomous](http://otonomos.com/) and [DAO.LINK](https://blog.slock.it/our-proposal-taking-ethereum-to-the-mainstream-with-the-ethereum-computer-493340aa1fe6#.3efnkn793) emerge to make everything smooth. Switzerland seems to be the preferred home of many cryptocompanies and foundations, because of its crypto-friendly laws.

Answer (score 3):

Check some [info](http://www.loc.gov/law/help/bitcoin-survey/) on the legal status of cryptos in various countries. In many countries you can probably pay something like property with cryptos, just like you can pay things with gold and other stuffs.

It's probably very complicated, I suggest you consult an expert or a lawyer that is well aware of the legal status of cryptos in your country.